# CKEDITOR replace() referencing element doesn't work

Tags: jquery, ckeditor

I'm wondering, why I can't call the `replace()` function from `CKEDITOR` on an element, but I can if I give that element an ID, then call `replace` referencing that ID?
This is my function (ele is from `onclick=myFunction(this)` )

```
myFunction(ele){
    if(~$(ele).closest("ul").attr("class").indexOf("sh_connect")){
        var _sh = $(ele).closest("li").find("[name='shortcode[]']");
        _sh.attr("id","curr_edit");
        //CKEDITOR.replace(_sh) //doesn't work
        CKEDITOR.replace('curr_edit'); //works
        console.log(_sh); //prints [textarea#curr_edit.form-control, prevObject: r.fn.init(1)]
    }
}
```

How can I call `replace()` referencing just the element?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`var _sh = $(ele).closest("li").find("[name='shortcode[]']");` gives you a jQuery object. You need to iterate over it to access each DOM element and call `replace()` like this:

```
_sh.each(function() {
    CKEDITOR.replace(this);
});
```

Or if you know that `find()` will return only one element, you can use the DOM element like this:

```
CKEDITOR.replace(_sh.get(0));
```

or

```
CKEDITOR.replace(_sh[0]);
```

More info:

[.each()](http://api.jquery.com/each/)

> The `.each()` method is designed to make DOM looping constructs concise
>   and less error-prone. When called it iterates over the DOM elements
>   that are part of the jQuery object. Each time the callback runs, it is
>   passed the current loop iteration, beginning from 0. More importantly,
>   the callback is fired in the context of the current DOM element, so
>   the keyword `this` refers to the element.

[.get()](https://api.jquery.com/get/)

> The `.get()` method grants access to the DOM nodes underlying each jQuery object. With an index specified, `.get( index )` retrieves a single element.
>
> `console.log( $( "li" ).get( 0 ) );`
>
> Each jQuery object also masquerades as an array, so we can use the array dereferencing operator to get at the list item instead:
>
> `console.log( $( "li" )[ 0 ] );`

Comment: thank you, yes my find returns one element, now it works :D

Answer (score 0):

```
<textarea id="myfield" name="myfield"></textarea>
...
CKEDITOR.replace( 'myfield' );

var textarea = document.body.appendChild( document.createElement( 'textarea' ) );
CKEDITOR.replace( textarea );
```

Comment: Yes you don't need to create an element. I think it will be work with `name`.

Comment: but all my textarea's have the same name, because I need them as arrays